# How to redirect two different ranks to the same page

Tags: php, mysql

Currently coding an admin panel to manage a website which i'm creating.

The site has 3 ranks:

- 0 = User
- 1 = Admin (isAdmin)
- 2 = Regular Staff (isAdmin2)

I would like to redirect both staff and admins to home.php. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

`if(!$user->isAdmin($odb)) elseif (!$user->isAdmin2($odb)){
        header('home.php');
        exit;
    }`

If you're wondering why I have two separate ranks it is because I would at some point only like to allow Admin to access certain pages.

Not sure where i'm going wrong but this works for just allowing access for the Admin rank:

`if(!$user->isAdmin($odb)){
        header('home.php');
        exit;
    }`

Comment: where is the code for `$user` object and `isAdmin()` method?

Comment: Think about using something like rbac, then your have a single method to check the users role as its has inheritance, then if you got 50 roles in the system you not got 50 if elses..

Comment: In that 1st snippet, there isn't any code for the 2st if being true. It should be ```if($user->isAdmin($odb) || $user->isAdmin2($odb))```

Comment: this `isAdmin()` method is within the `user` class:

`function isAdmin($odb){
   $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?");
   $SQL -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
   $rank = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
   if ($rank == 1){
    return true;
   } else{
    return false;
   }
  }`

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a fully fledged library at this point. Tho I do suggest you consider a grouping system (depends on how big this might grow). So you can add users to groups, and groups to pages/resources etc. A table with rows for each group and a table for rows with each resource and/or page and which groups can access them. If you need anything more complex then I suggest something more substantial than the way you are going :)

Comment: Haha them famous last words.. Customer: *dont bother at this point*.. 2 weeks down the line.. can we add users and editors .. actually can we add roles to the admin interface and why can't admin2 can see admin1 stuff and can we add super admin who sees everything plus I only want this admin to see admin3's stuff, can we do it this week please? ;p

Comment: here is the user class https://codeshare.io/axqNOP @James

Comment: @Lawrence that's the story of my life..

Comment: Zac, I know my code works with your user class. Answer is below & also Sloan posted that code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($user->isAdmin($odb) || $user->isAdmin2($odb)){
// Send staff or admin to home 
} else {

}
```

This will send both roles to home. As long as your isAdmin2 works.

In admin2 function you need to make sure rank # matches !